# Kinesis live stream with Gstreamer pipeline as python subprocess with sudo : "No such element or plugin 'kvssink'"

Tags: python, subprocess, gstreamer, amazon-kinesis

I have tested the example given by the [Amazon Kinesis docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/examples-gstreamer-plugin.html):

`$ gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://YourCameraRtspUrl" short-header=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264, format=avc,alignment=au ! kvssink stream-name="YourStreamName" storage-size=512 access-key="YourAccessKey" secret-key="YourSecretKey" aws-region="YourAWSRegion"`

This works fine when I run it in the terminal, however when I try to integrate it into a python program as a subprocess it throws the error `No such element or plugin 'kvssink'`. The program needs to be run as sudo, as it is a bigger project with multiple other locations requiring heightened permissions. I have tested starting the subprocess without sudo which makes this subprocess work, but breaks everything else. Any attempts to demote the subprocess have not been successful. This is what I currently have:

```
   # Demote user for subprocess
   def demote():

    def set_ids():
        os.setgid(1000)
        os.initgroups("tsmc", 1000)
        os.setuid(1000)

    return set_ids()


    # Set environment variables
    kinesisEnv = os.environ.copy()
    kinesisEnv["PATH"]='/home/tsmc/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/bin:/home/tsmc/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
    kinesisEnv["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]="/home/tsmc/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/lib:"
    kinesisEnv["USER"]="tsmc"
    kinesisEnv["USERNAME"]="tsmc"
    kinesisEnv["LOGNAME"]="tsmc"
    kinesisEnv["PWD"]="/home/tsmc/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp"
    kinesisEnv["HOME"]="/home/tsmc/"

    # gstreamer inspect command to inspect kvssink
    command = 'gst-inspect-1.0 kvssink'    

    # Start subprocess
    kinesisProcess = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), preexec_fn=demote, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    output = kinesisProcess.communicate()[0]
    print(output.decode("utf-8"))
```

Does anyone know what I could do about this?

Thank you.

Comment: GStreamer uses an environment variable called "GST_PLUGIN_PATH" to decide where to search for plugins. Have you tried adding the path that contains the kvssink plugin to that environment variable?